# SQL group by - How to group by two columns, date and hour

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Please see code below I'm trying to group by 2 columns:

```
select 
    "dimension.date", "dimension.hour",
    "order_name", "order_id",     
    sum("column.total_line_item_level_impressions") as total_impressions, 
    sum("column.total_line_item_level_clicks") as total_clicks
from 
    data_test.order_check
where 
    order_id = '2881013495' and "dimension.hour" = '6'
group by
    "dimension.date", "dimension.hour",
```

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Please add sample data.  Note that grouping by the hour makes no sense here given that your restrict the hour to only 6.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The query errors out expecting all my column to be aggregates or to be added to the group by clause

Comment: Because each expression should be aggregated, placed in `group by` clause or be a function of aggregated expression or `group by` expression. Otherwise DBMS doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: I'm trying to get total impressions and clicks for hour 6 for the specified order id

Comment: Please, [do not post images of data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#285557). You may check [sql tab wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) for information on how to ask SQL question

Comment: So you may group by `order_id` also or remove it from `select` list (as you already know it upfront).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, the below query did the job

```
select
sum("column.total_line_item_level_impressions") AS total_impressions, 
sum("column.total_line_item_level_clicks") as total_clicks, 
"dimension.date"
from data_test_order_check
where order_id='2881013495' AND "dimension.hour"='6'
GROUP BY "dimension.date"
```